# objective progress status

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

If Objective has a readSatisfiedStatus = true and we need its Objective Progress Status; In this case, which Objective Progress Status must be retrieved? Local Objective Progress Status or Shared Global Objective Progress Status?

Answer (score 1):

1. "`readSatisifiedStatus`" reads the satisfied status of a global objective declared in a different activity where the mapInfo has set "`writeSatisfiedStatus`" to true.
2. EDIT "`readSatisifiedStatus`" reads `satisfied status` and "`Objective progress status`".  "`Objective progress status`" is determined by the LMS based on the "`objective success status`". If "`Objective success status`" is "`Unknown`", "`Objective progress status`" is set to "false", if "`Objective success status`" is set to "passed" or "failed", "`Objective progress status`" is set to "true". "objective satisfied status" has three states: null, true, and false: They are in parallel with the three states of the "objective success status" (unkonwn, passed, failed).
3. When a local objective is mapped to a global objective, both of them have the same value.

This diagram explains the states of the objectives

[image: Diagram 2]

Comment: You said "When a local objective is mapped to a global objective, both of them have the same value". What does 'both' refer to?

Comment: local objective and global objective

Comment: If targetObjectiveID for a local objective is "g-Obj1" and there are two targetObjectiveIDs (g-Obj1). In this case, which global objective should be mapped to the mentioned local objective?

![mapInfo][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqcxZ.png

Comment: "targetObjectiveID" is the ID of the global objective declared in Activity 1 and read in Activity 2. It refers to the same global objective. Think of "global objective" as a variable you declare and assign a vlue to it in one place and read its value in a different place.

Comment: See the the picture I provided in the previous comment; Does Activity 2 read Objective Satisfied Status from Activity 3? If so, why? If no, why?